# Connect 4 java horizontal not being recognized

Tags: java

Everything works but my horizontal win conditions which I find weird because my vertical works fine but I can't put my finger on why a horizontal won't but my vertical can I assume that you could switch the for loop for rows and col and vice versa for horizontal and vertical but its seeming to fail here

Ive tried looking up stuff but everywhere is saying to do what I already did

```
public class Connect4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // DON'T MODIFY THE MAIN METHOD UNLESS FOR DEBUGGING
  //MAKE SURE YOU GET RID OF YOUR MODIFICATIONS HERE BEFORE 
SUBMISSION

String[][] board = createEmptyBoard();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean bl = true;

printPattern(board);

while(bl) {

    int player1 = 1 , player2 = 2 ,  userInput;


   System.out.println("Please drop a RED disk at the column between 
0 and 6:");
    userInput = input.nextInt();
    dropDisk(board, userInput , player1);
    printPattern(board);

   System.out.println("Please drop a YELLOW disk at the column 
between 0 and 6:");
   userInput  = input.nextInt();
   dropDisk(board, userInput , player2);
   printPattern(board);  


    String win = checkWinner(board);

    if(!win.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(win + " is the winner!");
            break;
        }
    /*
    Write code to announce  if there is  winner and end the game
    */

     } 
    }
     public static String[][] createEmptyBoard() {
   /* This method prints the first empty pattern for the game
   DON'T MODIFY THIS METHOD
   */
    String[][] f = new String[7][15];
    for (int i =0;i<f.length;i++) {
          for (int j =0;j<f[i].length;j++) {

             if (j% 2 == 0) f[i][j] ="|";
             else f[i][j] = " ";
             if (i==6) f[i][j]= "-";
         }
       }
    return f;

     } // end of createEmptyBoard 


     public static void printPattern(String[][] brd) {

         for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

      System.out.println(brd[i][0] + brd[i][1]+ brd[i][2]+ brd[i]
[3]+ brd[i][4]+ brd[i][5]+ brd[i][6]+ brd[i][7]+ brd[i][8]+ brd[i]
[9]+ 

brd[i][10]+ brd[i][11]+ brd[i][12]+ brd[i][13]+ brd[i][14]);


     }

     } // end of printPattern

     public static String dropDisk(String[][] brd, int position, 
int player) {

    if(position < 0 || position > 6){

             return null;

         }

    String disk = player == 1 ? "R" : "Y";

         int col = 2 * position + 1;
         // start looking for a free slot at the very bottom

         int row = 5;

         while (row >= 0 && !brd[row][col].equals(" ")) {

         // move one row up

         row--;

         }

// free slot found, disk can be placed

if (row >= 0) {

    brd[row][col] = disk;

    return disk;

}

return null;

  } // end of dropDisk


   public static String checkWinner(String[][] brd) {      

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++){

            if(brd[i][j].equals("R")){

                count++;

            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }

            if(count == 4){

                return "R";

            }

        }        

    }

    //Vertical Check for "Y"
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++){

            if(brd[i][j].equals("Y")){

                count++;

            }

            else{
                count = 0;
            }

            if(count == 4){

                return "Y";

            }
        }        
    }

    // Horizontal Check for "R"
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){

        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){

            if(brd[j][i].equals("R")){

                count++;

            }

            else {

                count = 0;

            }

            if(count == 4){

                return "R";

            }

        }     

    }

    // Horizontal Check for "Y"
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){

        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){

            if(brd[j][i].equals("Y")){

                count++;

            }

            else {
                count = 0;
            }

            if(count == 4){

                return "Y";

            }

        }    

    }

    // Check for a diagonal to the bottom and right
    for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-4; i++){

        for(int j = 1; j < brd[i].length-7; j = j + 2){

            if(brd[i][j].equals("R")){

                if(brd[i+1][j+2].equals("R") && brd[i+2]
[j+4].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j+6].equals("R")){

                    return "R";

                }

            }
            else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y")){

                if(brd[i+1][j+2].equals("Y") && brd[i+2]\
[j+4].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j+6].equals("Y")){

                    return "Y";

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // Check for a diagonal to the bottom and left
    for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-4; i++){

        for(int j = brd[i].length-2; j >= 7; j = j - 2){

            if(brd[i][j].equals("R")){

                if(brd[i+1][j-2].equals("R") && brd[i+2][j-
4].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j-6].equals("R")){

                    return "R";
                }
            }
            else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y")){

                if(brd[i+1][j-2].equals("Y") && brd[i+2][j-
4].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j-6].equals("Y")){

                    return "Y";

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return "";

}

}
```

Comment: Your loop is checking every column, but even-numbered columns always contain `"|"`, so `count` will never be greater than 1 in those loops.  Change your `j` loop to only check odd numbered columns.

Comment: @VGR would I do this by using the %

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j < 14; j += 2)` is sufficient.  Obviously, in places where you use `i` to loop over a row, you would make that change to `i` rather than `j`.

Comment: Got a out of bounce error @VGR I'm still not following

Answer (score 0):

In your board setup, you have :

```
 if (j% 2 == 0) f[i][j] ="|";
```

In other words, you're having your columns alternate between the "R"/"Y"/" " playing positions, and "|" column markers.

So you can never have 4 "R"s or "Y"s in a horizontal (or diagonal) line - you'd have "R","|","R","|","R","|","R".

Better would be to remove the "|" from your array - you don't need to store them, and it just really complicates all your processing.  Simply have the array storing your playing pieces, and only use the "|" when printing out.

Comment: The comments in the code seem to indicate that the assignment does not allow Nhami to modify how the board is stored.

Comment: @VGR Yes, you are quite right, I missed that.  Gosh, how I hate exercises where students are given poor-quality examples to work from.  That being so, your comment is the right way to go.